# display candidate information to user only on request in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have candidate details form in my application..so when vendor posting the candidate details..user will got the candidate details through mail..after click on mail they can see candidate details..

so what i want to do is when vendor click on submit i need to give popup like "you want to show contact info or not" if they click on yes..user got candidate details with contact info(email,phone number)..if no user has to send request for contact info..when user send request for contact info then vendor can show candidate info to user..

How will we do that in codeigniter..
Can anyone help me..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: keep one input type with 'hidden' and then set a value of it on the click of 'yes/no' of the pop-up. post that value at the time of sending mail. then check if it is no then don't display contact info otherwise display it

Comment: that is ok..then once user got mail user need to  do request for contact info right?then how can vendor show that contact info to user..

Comment: to display contact info to the user, vendor have to send mail again to that user

Comment: ok..if it is possible can you please xplain in code..how to give popup and all the things..i know how to send  mail.just explain me the flow..

Comment: hire me and i can do that. just google it man!! how to show popup and display value accordingly

Comment: ok thank you..give your answer properly...then by that i will vote you up..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136347/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-bharathi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow below steps:**

1. keep one input type with 'hidden' and then set a value of it on the
   click of 'yes/no' of the pop-up. post that value at the time of
   sending mail. then check if it is no then don't display contact info
   otherwise display it.
2. to display contact info to the user, vendor have to send mail again
   to that user